# Monit appears to be working on command line but get 404 'There is no service by that name' in web interface

Tags: ubuntu, monit

Monit seems to be working, but when I go to the web interface at port :2812 I get:

```
Not Found
There is no service by that name

monit 5.2.5
```

--

But again, things appear ok on the CLI

```
-->:/var/log$ sudo monit -t
Control file syntax OK
-->:/var/log$ sudo monit status
The Monit daemon 5.2.5 uptime: 11m 

System 'system_mydomain.net'
  status                            running
  monitoring status                 monitored
  load average                      [0.00] [0.01] [0.05]
  cpu                               0.0%us 0.0%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                      645520 kB [63.4%]
  swap usage                        213128 kB [10.1%]
  data collected                    Wed Feb 15 06:27:26 2012
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your monit.conf or monitrc config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample `/etc/monit.conf` configuration file. Make sure you have something similar to the line beginning with "set httpd port 2812 and..." in your configuration file.

```
set daemon 60
set logfile syslog facility log_daemon
set idfile /tmp/monit.id
set statefile /tmp/monit.state
set mailserver localhost
set alert systems@abcd.net
set httpd port 2812 and
     #use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
      allow 172.16.16.0/255.255.255.0
      allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
      allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
  check system Fruity
    if loadavg (1min) > 6 then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 6 then alert
    if memory usage > 90% then alert
    if swap usage > 20% then alert
    if cpu usage (user) > 90% then alert
    if cpu usage (system) > 75% then alert
    if cpu usage (wait) > 75% then alert
```

Comment: Thanks, I was allowing the server ip but not the machine i'm accessing it from.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when I misconfigured my Nginx. After reading the [wiki](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Nginx), I resolved monit 404 errors. Here's my /etc/nginx/conf.d/monit.conf:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  my.server.name;

    location /monit/ {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow 192.0.0.0/8;
            deny all;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2812;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            rewrite ^/monit/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the site is behind NGINX proxy. Solved by this snipped:

```
location /monit/ {
        rewrite ^/monit/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:2812; 
        proxy_redirect  http://127.0.0.1:2812 /monit; 
        proxy_cookie_path / /monit/;
    }
```

Source: https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Nginx